# Visual Studio & Git: Not adding new files to or removing deleted files from project

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

We have tested **Visual Studio 2017** with a local Git-server.
Git works fine but Visual Studio doesn't add new files to the project, and doesn't remove deleted files from a project.

So when we pull changes made by another developer the files on filesystem-level are updated, but the project is not. This causes Visual Studio to complain that it can't find files and makes that we manually have to  add new files to the project.

Is this suppose to work like this? We have used TFS in the past and I am pretty sure that this was better integrated. It is a surprise to me because in Team Explorer you can push/pull and see all changes. I would say that it would be possible to reflect those changes in the project. It is not that all changes happen outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: A common reason for this is not checking in the project file.

Comment: Thanks @KenTucker, but this would mean you have to merge project files when multiple users work in parallel. Is the project-file suitable for this? Or will it get corrupted by merging?

Comment: You should be fine merging project files.